# Undefined method encode_www_form when working with Twitter API

Tags: ruby, json, api, twitter

I'm trying to fetch a basic list of Twitter favorites from the API using `Ruby`, but I keep bumping my head on this error.

```
baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"
path    = "/1.1/favorites/list.json"
query   = URI.encode_www_form(
            "screen_name" => "twitterapi",
            "count" => 10)
address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}#{query}")
```

I always get a `undefined method encode_www_form for URI:Module (NoMethodError)` error whenever I run it.

Comment: did you require 'uri'?

Comment: Yes, but no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
URI.encode_www_form_component(yourStringToEncodeHere)
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work. I found out that the problem was that I had forgotten the last , after 10 and before the closing ).